# Python 3; applying xarray.DataArray.weighted operation and receiving error message 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'weighted'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray, weighted

I have a seemingly simple issue I have been unable to resolve.

I wish to apply the weighted function (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.weighted.html) to a data array as per the following method: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/area_weighted_temperature.html.

I am getting the error message "'DataArray' object has no attribute 'weighted'"

For example, I get this message when using the tutorial data:

```
In:
# Load data
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")

# To data array
air = ds.air
air

Out:
<xarray.DataArray 'air' (time: 2920, lat: 25, lon: 53)>
array([[[241.2    , 242.5    , ..., 235.5    , 238.59999],
        [243.79999, 244.5    , ..., 235.29999, 239.29999],
        ...,
        [295.9    , 296.19998, ..., 295.9    , 295.19998],
        [296.29   , 296.79   , ..., 296.79   , 296.6    ]],

       [[242.09999, 242.7    , ..., 233.59999, 235.79999],
        [243.59999, 244.09999, ..., 232.5    , 235.7    ],
        ...,
        [296.19998, 296.69998, ..., 295.5    , 295.1    ],
        [296.29   , 297.19998, ..., 296.4    , 296.6    ]],

       ...,

       [[245.79   , 244.79   , ..., 243.98999, 244.79   ],
        [249.89   , 249.29   , ..., 242.48999, 244.29   ],
        ...,
        [296.29   , 297.19   , ..., 295.09   , 294.38998],
        [297.79   , 298.38998, ..., 295.49   , 295.19   ]],

       [[245.09   , 244.29   , ..., 241.48999, 241.79   ],
        [249.89   , 249.29   , ..., 240.29   , 241.68999],
        ...,
        [296.09   , 296.88998, ..., 295.69   , 295.19   ],
        [297.69   , 298.09   , ..., 296.19   , 295.69   ]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 ... 25.0 22.5 20.0 17.5 15.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 ... 322.5 325.0 327.5 330.0
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2013-01-01 ... 2014-12-31T18:00:00
Attributes:
    long_name:     4xDaily Air temperature at sigma level 995
    units:         degK
    precision:     2
    GRIB_id:       11
    GRIB_name:     TMP
    var_desc:      Air temperature
    dataset:       NMC Reanalysis
    level_desc:    Surface
    statistic:     Individual Obs
    parent_stat:   Other
    actual_range:  [185.16 322.1 ]
```

My code:

```
In:
%matplotlib inline
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

weights = np.cos(np.deg2rad(air.lat))
weights.name = "weights"

air_weighted = air.weighted(weights)
air_weighted

Out:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-648627c40eb5> in <module>
----> 1 air_weighted = air.weighted(weights)
      2 air_weighted

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    177                     return source[name]
    178         raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
--> 179                              (type(self).__name__, name))
    180 
    181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'weighted'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I’m guessing you are using an older version of xarray.  `weighted` was only added in xarray version 15.1.  I would try updating if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I had begun to consider this too!